# strange behavior of android application

Tags: android, exception

I'm developing a large project with android technology
sometimes I have some exceptions like (Out Of Memory Error) on small devices
what I do when an exception occurred is to re-open the application

what happen that it leaves the previous process open and open a new process with new instance of application

I have tried to make
finish()
kill process
System.exit

to close the application and re-open it again but nothing works for me

any help please ???

Comment: what is the actual application's work? and r u using images or any media in your application?

Comment: are u using huge number of images  files in your application.

Comment: yes I'm loading data and images from server side backend and store them in local cache of device

Comment: ok, then it is the problem with image size, just try to load small size image, then it will work fine. it depending on RAM and when you are loading large images, it will exceeds your HEAP size and application stops working. and sometimes it hangs up device also.

Answer (score 1):

First Thing you have to take care of, is  Heap size.. You can track How much memory is getting consumed when your are running application. Under DDMS perspective there is a heap tab which will give you info about how much memory is consumed when you are running your application.
on what version of the android you are testing ? Android Os will allocate some memory for each application to run.In android 2.2 16mb will be allocated for one application. Version 2.3 allocates 24Mb  for an application ,Android 3.0 allocates 42Mb. try testing on different versions of android, you will get to know..

Answer (score 0):

Out of memory happens when RAM in a device is utilized fully, the system will throw this error and kill/restart the process. You need to find the appropriate place where you use the most of memory and handle the memory properly. Out of Memory generally happens because of poor bitmap/image handling. Check your code where you handle Bitmaps/ImageViews/PNG's etc.

Answer (score 0):

Android default heap size is almost good for every heavy load jobs. Trace your code and find memory consuming parts of your code and try to optimize them. To do so, use HEAP tab in DDMS view in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

yes that is the problem .i have faced similar problem recently then i resized my `images` then my problem is solved.Try to find out a way how to reduce the `size of` the `images` which you are loading  from `sever side` `back-end`.